# Логируется ли информация по входящим письмам в Битрикс24?

Tags: битрикс24

Столкнулся с коробочной версией Битрикс24 и тут же прилетела проблема с почтой: пользователи получают письма от внешних отправителей с сильной задержкой (10+ часов). Имел ли кто опыт работы с данной CRM-системой (коробкой) и знает, логируются ли ивенты по входящим письмам в каком-либо файле? Исход нашел, а входа не вижу.